# How to get one row with MySQL and NodeJS ?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, express, postman

I am new developer **ReactJS**, I develop a table with **ReactJS** on the FrontEnd, **NodeJS** on BackEnd and **MySQL** about the database.

I want when I click on the view button on Action column, it will be redirected to another page, which display a list containing the result of the Select query, as below :

[image]

My router :

```
exports.viewclient = function(req, res) {
  var Code = req.query.Code;
    console.log(req.query.Code);

    connection.query('SELECT Code, Prenom, Nom, FAX, Telephone, Email, Adresse1, Adresse2  FROM clients  WHERE Code = ?',[Code],  function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
console.log(results);
    });

}
```

My server :

```
router.get('/viewclient/:Code', clients.viewclient);
```

When, I test the backend with Postman, `http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/:Code=1111` , it returns : `[]` and `console.log(req.query.Code)` returns `undefined`

How to fix that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need a couple of changes in your URL and code

The URL should be `http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/111`

In your controller

`console.log(req.params);`

Output

```
{ "Code": "111"}
```

Comment: `console.log(req.params)` returns `{ Code: '1111' }` and  `http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/1111` returns `[]`

Comment: What is the input URL for this `{ Code: '1111' }` output

Comment: When I edit my Select request like this : `'SELECT Code, Prenom, Nom, FAX, Telephone, Email, Adresse1, Adresse2  FROM clients  WHERE Code = ?',[req.params.Code],` it returns  `[{"Code":1111,"Prenom":"test","Nom":"test","FAX":"58985688888","Telephone":"58985699888","Email":"test@gmail.com","Adresse1":"","Adresse2":""}]`   but on ReactJS, nothing is displayed !

Comment: "but on ReactJS, nothing is displayed! " You are losing focus from your initial question,please ask a new question

Comment: @CodeLover BTW check your network console for the response if you need single row you can simply call `result[0]` returns the first row

Comment: I need when I click a button view for each row on the table, it will be redirected to the `http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/Code`, which containing list.